# RichTextbox TextRange highlight (position) incorrect

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

To find a search keyword in a RichtTextBox, I implemented  the following method:

```
private TextRange SearchText(TextPointer position, string searchText)
{
    while (position != null)
    {
        if (position.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
        {
            string textRun = position.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);

            // Find the starting index of any substring that matches "searchText".
            int indexInRun = textRun.IndexOf(searchText);
            if (indexInRun >= 0)
            {
                TextPointer start = position.GetPositionAtOffset(indexInRun);
                TextPointer end = start.GetPositionAtOffset(searchText.Length);
                return new TextRange(start, end);
            }
        }

        position = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    }
    return null;
}
```

To highlight the result TextRange of the SearchText method, I am using the following code (snippet):

```
        textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, _blueHighlightBackgroundColor);
        textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, SystemColors.WindowBrush);
        textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);

        FrameworkContentElement frameworkContentElement = (rtbResultText.Selection.Start.Parent as FrameworkContentElement);
        if (frameworkContentElement != null)
        {
            frameworkContentElement.BringIntoView();
        }
```

The text is highlighted, but the position of the highlight is incorrect. This is visualized in the next screenshot:

[image]

The light-blue is the selection and the dark-blue is the highlighted text. As you can see, the dark-blue highlight is 2 pixels too high (on the y-axis).

Do you know a solution to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

---

**Update 1:**

The light (pale) blue background is the one which I created manually with the mouse selection.

Comment: Is it because the bold text takes more vertical space?

Comment: @PSCr The issue persist after removing the 'FontWeights.Bold' code.

Comment: Sorry. I was just guessing. Where do you set the pale blue background?

Comment: @PScr The pale blue background is the one which I created manually with the mouse selection.

Comment: Yes, I see. Which makes me wonder if the mouse selection does something different from setti8 the background. Sorry, I don't know